# Show Json data with Laravel

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, laravel

I have a question. Currently, I keep a Json data type in my database, as I show it in the image. The data is named **date_table**.

[image]

where in my controller to extract the data I do it like this:

```
public function Detalle_serviciosHome(){
  $det_serv = Detalle_servicio::all();
  $detalles = json_decode($det_serv, true);
  dd($detalles);
}
```

and on my local server it shows it like that

[image]

How can I make the data display it and the data from date_table display it in a table? I really appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: can you give more explanation? if you want to render data in a table you have to use the blade views or use vue.js or somthing

Comment: try this package for datatables. https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables . Go through the docs, you will get to know what to do.

Comment: Always use variable names in English for more readibilty, although your native language is different.